# Why doesn't chrome.bluetooth work in a Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

Following the instructions on the Chrome App [Create Your First App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) page, I was able to create a simple app that I can run from **More tools** > **Extensions** in Chrome.

I then added `"bluetooth": {}` to the manifest, and added the following JS file to my code:

```
console.log('chrome.bluetooth');
console.log(chrome.bluetooth);

chrome.bluetooth.onAdapterStateChanged.addListener(function (state) {
  console.log('onAdapterStateChanged callback');
  console.log(state);
});

chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceAdded.addListener(function (device) {
  console.log('onDeviceAdded callback');
  console.log(device);
});

chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState(function (adapterInfo) {
  console.log('getAdapterState callback');
  console.log(adapterInfo);
});

chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function (deviceInfos) {
  console.log('getDevices callback');
  console.log(deviceInfos);
});

console.log('startDiscovery method call');
chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery(function () {
  console.log('startDiscovery callback');
  console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

However, it does not work.
I get the following output to the console; most notably the `startDiscovery` error at the end:

[image: chrome.bluetooth_startDiscovery_failure]

What would cause this to fail and why? How can I fix it?
I should note that I am using Chrome on Windows 7, if that affects anything.

Thank you.

Comment: The possible reasons for failure here are the adapter not being initialized, the app already having started discovery, or if the adapter isn't powered. See more details on the related issue reported here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434215

Comment: It's not possible for discovery to have already been started if I just started up the app, correct? Also, when you say "adapter", I assume you're referring to a Bluetooth device, correct? I'm honestly not sure if I have any connected to my PC. Could that be the issue? I have a wireless USB dongle for my Internet connection. Is that not a Bluetooth device? Thanks.

Comment: gui47, your comment helped guide me a lot. I pulled out my laptop and confirmed that it had a Bluetooth device in it from the Windows 7 Control Panel. I ran my same Chrome App on the laptop, and it properly detected the Bluetooth device without any failures. Thanks a lot. I guess the key was realizing that the code was correct, but my desktop PC just didn't have a Bluetooth device installed in it. Thanks again.